# How to make ProgressBar setProgress function move smoothly

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am trying to animate a progress bar based on a timer action. I need to be able to pause the timer and progress bar during the countdown. As I need to pause it it doesn't seem possible to use the following which produces a smooth animation:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mprogressBar, "progress", 0, 100);
anim.setDuration((seconds * 1000));
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.start();
```

So I am using the .setProgress(); instead to update the ProgressBar every second. However when setting the progress from an integer the progress bar jumps between phases which I want to make smooth unless there is a better way to accomplish this. Here is my current code:

```
public class Detail_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar mprogressBar;
    Integer seconds = 10;
    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            seconds -= 1;

            mprogressBar.setProgress(seconds);
            timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.detail_activity);

        mprogressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circular_progress_bar);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        b.setText("Start");
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button b = (Button) v;
            if (b.getText().equals("Stop")) {
                timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
                b.setText("Start");
            } else {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);

                b.setText("Stop");
            }
        }
    });
}

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
        Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_start);
        b.setText("Start");
    }
}
```

Comment: you need a pause and resume for the progress bar?

Comment: Yes, the timer is counting down but I want to be able to pause it at any time